# Appending and Iterating Through QList

Tags: c++, qt

My QList holds pointers to a class. I am trying to iterate through the QList, but all its elements seems to only contain the last pointer I assigned to the QList.

code:

```
QList<fooClass*> myList;

fooClass *pNewFooA = new fooClass("Bob");
myList.append(pNewFooA);

fooClass *pNewFooB = new fooClass("Jen");
myList.append(pNewFooB);

fooClass *pNewFooC = new fooClass("Mel");
myList.append(pNewFooC);

QList<fooClass*>::iterator i;
for (i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    cout << (*i)->getName() << "\n";
}
```

output:

```
Mel
Mel
Mel
```

Instead of using .append(), I also have tried the following but it did not work:

- myList.push_back("zoe");
- myList << "zoe";
- myList += "zoe";

fooClass.cpp

```
QString name = "";

QString fooClass::getName()
{
    return name;
}

fooClass::fooClass(QString newName)
{
    name = newName;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating your iterator on `QList<Slave*>` and not on `QList<fooClass*>`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant QList<fooClass*>. I just changed a few names around from my original code so it is easier to understand :)

Comment: We need  your `fooClass` declaration at least

Comment: Sorry about that, I just included it. I'm new to C++, so please bare with me.

Comment: Do you mean, your `name` variable is a _gloabl_ variable, not a memeber of `fooClass`?

Comment: Lol4t0: you should certainly post that as an answer, as it's definitely the problem (but I won't steal it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to code you showed, your `name` is *global* variable. It means, it is *only one* `name` variable in your program for *all* instances of `fooClass`. And every time you execute

```
name = newName;
```

you change the value of that variable.

If you want each `fooClass` to have its own name, you should make your `name` variable member of `fooClass` like that:

```
class fooClass
{
public:
    //some stuff here
private:
    QString name;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your list, make name private member of your fooClass in the header. Should be like that

```
class fooClass{
public:
  fooClass(QString newName);
  QString getName();
private:
  QString name;
};
```

And remove global variable name from cpp. You don't need to init QString with "" anyway.